# Add external website as frame within ipywidgets widget?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I would like to embed a website, as a frame, into my Jupyter notebook within an `ipwidgets` `widget`, such as `GridspecLaout`.  Here is how I can create the frame using `magic` commands:

```py
%%html
<iframe src="https://mywebsite.com/" width="100%" height="1000"></iframe>
```

Adding the frame to a cell in a `GridspecLaout` would allow me to hide this frame dynamically versus having it always open in a static notebook cell.

thx

Comment: Noting similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71924109/8508004).