# Jupyter Notebook Voila Extension not displaying HTML File

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook

I am running a Jupyter Notebook and using the Voila extension to display a dashboard view. I have an interactive chart using plotly.express which I am saving to a HTML file so I can add it to an IFrame to display in the Voila dashboard.
I am using IPhython to display the IFrame

```
from IPython.display import display, clear_output, IFrame, Image, HTML
display(IFrame(src="./test2.html", width=700, height=600))
```

This works fine in the Notebook but when I run Voila I am getting a 403 error saying that the test2.html is not whitelisted.
How can I whitelist the file while using the Jupyter Notebook Voila Extension?

Comment: I think the issue is that Voila only allows rendering of output that is mainly ipywidgets. Or stuff you can direct to the `out` handler, which wraps it in widgets. You cannot use just anything the notebook can render. (Noting I see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66642199/8508004) with no reply yet.) There is a widget that maybe could be an add-in to provide this ability, see [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2264). Here is the solution I think: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/can-output-widget-capture-iframe/13841?u=fomightez

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/can-output-widget-capture-iframe/13841/2?u=fomightez):

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, IFrame

out = widgets.Output()

@out.capture()
def render():
    display(IFrame(src='./test2.html',width=700, height=600))
```